# Would removing the back-board of cupboards help against mould/mold?

Tags: mold, furniture

Would removing the back-board of cupboards help against mould/mold?

In our new (to us) semi-basement flat we have a relatively small condensation problem, generally behind  cupboards... kitchen cabinets, bathroom cabinets and wardrobes.

I'm thinking of removing the back boards for all of them, for the following reasons..

1 They are mould contaminated already

2 Not knowing if the last clean is working is worrying, this way it can be monitored easily

3 New mould can be attacked immediately, without having to move/dismantle anything

4 More air can circulate

Downsides...?

What are the downsides of not having back to cupboards? Are they necessary, structrural or in any way important that I just don-t know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are structural, but if you leave the mounting rails at top and bottom, the middle could be opened, if the cabinet have a normal load.

A full back helps resist racking.  Its less important if several cabinets are attached together as a group.

Of course, exterior water intrusion is your real culprit and the best focus during the spring: downspouts and reversed grade toward house are the two most common causes.

Comment: You can compensate for any strength loss, by adding more screws into the wall.

Comment: Thanks both of you, @bryce too, Now I have to ask a different question!!! http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/38438/how-can-i-prevent-racking-on-a-large-free-standing-wardrobe. Feel free to help me on that one too!!

Comment: A series of 4" holes (rent a hole saw bit) will give you 80% of the drying and leave 90% of the strength.  (Numbers are made up, but roughly correct).